# Your message was not delivered. Discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot. when I send commands on the server from my account with the owner role, then everything is OK, it is executed.
[photo_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF3Cf.png)

If I switch to another account that has the everyone role, then the bot stupidly does not react.
[photo_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzBuV.png)
here is a piece of code:

```
import discord 
 
from discord.ext import commands 
from dislash import InteractionClient, Option, OptionType 
 
 
 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!') 
inter_client = InteractionClient(bot) 
 
@bot.event 
async def on_ready(): 
    print('Bot is launch!') 
 
 
@inter_client.slash_command(description="Says Hello") 
async def hello(ctx): 
    await ctx.respond(content='asfd', ephemeral=True)

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: Give a feedback about your discord.py version, because in v2 version there are `Intents` and you need to configure them for bot running correctly.

Comment: That looks like from a DM, but that's also what discord sends you in the generic forbidden in the client. It may because the default role is missing permissions to use commands - make sure they're enabled for the bot and the user.

Comment: If it's in a direct message, and the person effectively has dms disabled (for each mutual server the bot is in), then this could occur

Comment: @PatrykSzczepański discord.py==1.7.3